# Why does forEach method accept lambda that invokes method with multiple arguments when Consumer only takes one argument?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I am playing with `forEach` on a `List<String>`, and I'm confused about why the following line is acceptable:

```
policies.forEach(policy -> test.addToDatabase(policy, stats));
```

Since `forEach` requires a `Consumer`, and the `Consumer` accept method only takes one argument, I don't understand why the call to `addtoDatabase` is acceptable, as it takes two arguments. See below for full test code. Note that I am only playing around here to learn, so this code is not meant to be perfect or elegant.

```
public class ConsumerTest {

    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsumerTest test = new ConsumerTest();
        List<String> policies = new ArrayList<>();
        policies.add("11111");
        policies.add("22222");
        policies.add("33333");
        policies.add("44444");
        policies.add("55555");
        Stats stats = test.new Stats();
        policies.forEach(policy -> test.addToDatabase(policy, stats));
        System.out.println("Success count: " + stats.getSuccessCount() + "\nFailure count: " + stats.getFailureCount());
    }

    private void addToDatabase(String policy, Stats stats) {
        // simulate success/failure adding to DB with Random
        if (random.nextBoolean()) {
            stats.incrementSuccessCount();
            System.out.println("Success for Policy " + policy);
        } else {
            stats.incrementFailureCount();
            System.out.println("Failure for Policy " + policy);
        }
    }

    class Stats {
        private int successCount;
        private int failureCount;
        public void incrementSuccessCount() {
            successCount++;
        }
        public void incrementFailureCount() {
            failureCount++;
        }
        public int getSuccessCount() {
            return successCount;
        }
        public int getFailureCount() {
            return failureCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Consumer only accepts one argument: `policy`. The other variable is captured. It does not matter what you do inside a lambda, if you call a method or just do some calculations or both, the arguments are listed on the right side of the `->` arrow.

Comment: And `stats` needs to be (effectively) final for it to work.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you, yes I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am playing with forEach on a List of Strings, and I'm confused about why the following line is acceptable:
>
> `policies.forEach(policy -> test.addToDatabase(policy, stats));`

It is. You confuse the parameter of the `Iterable::forEach` with the parameters of the statements inside the lambda expression. Since the only parameter inside the [`Iterable::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) which is nothing than an implementation of the very same anonymous class:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = new Consumer<>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(final String policy) {
        test.addToDatabase(policy, stats)
    }
};

policies.forEach(consumer);
```

It is the same as:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = policy -> test.addToDatabase(policy, stats);
policies.forEach(consumer);
```

What is inside doesn't matter - the number of passed parameters into `Iterable::forEach` remains only one:

```
policies.forEach(policy -> {
    log.info("adding to database");
    test.addToDatabase(policy, stats);
    log.info("added to database");
});
```

There is theoretically an unlimited number of statements and variables you can work with. The only condition that whatever you use inside the lambda expression must be [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class).